# matplotlib show many images in single pdf page

Tags: python, image, pdf, matplotlib

Given an image of unknown size as input, the following `python` script shows it 8 times in a single `pdf` page:

```
pdf = PdfPages( './test.pdf' )
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 4)

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax1.imshow( _img )

ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax2.imshow( _img )

ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[2])
ax3.imshow( _img )

# so on so forth...

ax8 = plt.subplot(gs[7])
ax8.imshow( _img )

pdf.savefig()
pdf.close()
```

The input image can have different size (unknown a priori). I tried using the function `gs.update(wspace=xxx, hspace=xxx)` to change the spacing between the images, hoping that `matplotlib` would automagically resize and redistribute the images to have least white space possible. However, as you can see below, it didn't work as I expected.

> Is there a better way to go to achieve the following?

1. Have images saved with max resolution possible
2. Have less white space possible

Ideally I would like the 8 images to completely will the page size of the `pdf` (with minimum amount of margin needed).

[image]

[image]

Comment: @hitzg - Yeah it did! I was waiting for a bit more feedback but then totally forgot to accept. sorry!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You were on the right path: `hspace` and `wspace` control the spaces between the images. You can also control the margins on the figure with `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.image as mimage
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

_img = mimage.imread('test.jpg')

pdf = PdfPages( 'test.pdf' )
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 4, top=1., bottom=0., right=1., left=0., hspace=0.,
        wspace=0.)

for g in gs:
    ax = plt.subplot(g)
    ax.imshow(_img)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
#    ax.set_aspect('auto')

pdf.savefig()
pdf.close()
```

Result:

[image]

If you want your images to really cover all the available space, then you can set the aspect ratio to auto:

```
ax.set_aspect('auto')
```

Result:

[image]